# Как мне данные из структуры записать в файл с помощью fprintf

Tags: c++, c, файлы

```
struct Department1
{
char NameOfSpecialist[100];
char NameOfFamily1[40];
int colChidInFamily1;
char NameOfFamily2[40];
int colChidInFamily2;
char NameOfFamily3[40];
int colChidInFamily3;
int ChildrenInDepartment;
};
void AddInfo(Department1*Dep, int k)
{
for (int i = 0; i<k; i++) {
    cout << "======  Отдел № " << i + 1 << "=====" << endl;
    cout << "Введите Имя куратора: ";
    cin >> Dep[i].NameOfSpecialist;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Введите инициплы первой семьи :";
    cin >> Dep[i].NameOfFamily1;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Введите колличсетво детей:";
    cin >> Dep[i].colChidInFamily1;
    cout << "\n";
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Введите инициплы второй семьи :";
    cin >> Dep[i].NameOfFamily2;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Введите колличсетво детей:";
    cin >> Dep[i].colChidInFamily2;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Введите инициплы третьей семьи :";
    cin >> Dep[i].NameOfFamily3;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Введите колличсетво детей:";
    cin >> Dep[i].colChidInFamily3;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\n" << endl;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае ваша структура удовлетворяет условиям plain old data, так что записать можно просто бинарно, соответствующим образом открыв файл:

```
Department1 * Det;
...
ofstream of(...,ios::binary);
...
of.write((char*)Det,sizeof(Department1));
```

Ну, а читать - аналогично, с помощью `read`.

Answer (score 0):

У вас в структуре обычные числа и строки, так что просто

```
FILE * f = fopen("filename","wt");
if (f == NULL) { Ошибка! }

Department1 D;

fprintf(f,"Имя куратора: %s\n",D.NameOfSpecialist);
fprintf(f,"Количество детей: %d\n",D.colChidInFamily1);
```

и так далее, по всем полям...